# How to compare two datasets having almost the same y-axis but different x-axis

Tags: plotting, programming

I have plots of two datasets that have almost the same values on the y-axis but different values on the x-axis. lets suppose `p1={x1,y1}` and `p1={x2,y2}`. `y1` and `y2` have almost the same value, for example y1 = 2 and y2 = 2.05. How can I equate `x1` with `x2` by comparing the `y1` and `y2` values?

I used this code but it doesn't work:

```
p1=[{{1,2}, {2,5}, {3,6}}
p2={{10,2.03}, {4,5.06}, {7,6.02}};
p1x = Interpolation[p1];
p2x = Interpolation[p2];
Plot[p1x[p2x[V]], {V, 0, 9}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  At a minimum, provide two representative data sets.

Comment: i used mathematica.

Comment: Copy and paste into your question (in Raw InputForm) a minimal working example of what you did in Mathematica.

Comment: P1x = Interpolation[P1]
P2x = Interpolation[P2]
Plot[ P1x[P2x[V]], {V, 0, 9}]

Comment: Are your datasets usually this small? If `p1` and `p2` consisted of more values that might change how this problem could be approached.

Comment: p1 and p2 have a long data sheet. just for example, i used 3 values

Answer (score 1):

```
p1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}};

p2 = {{10, 2.03}, {4, 5.06}, {7, 6.02}};
```

Since you want to compare values of `x` for comparable values of `y`, reverse the coordinates of the points.

```
p1r = Reverse /@ p1;

p2r = Reverse /@ p2;

ListLinePlot[{p1r, p2r}, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"y", "x"}), 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"p1r", "p2r"}, {.6, .75}]]
```

[image]

To use `Interpolation`

```
x1 = Interpolation[p1r, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

x2 = Interpolation[p2r, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

Plot[{x1[y], x2[y]}, {y, 2.03, 6},
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Red, Point[p1r], Blue, Point[p2r]},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"y", "x"}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.5, .75}]]
```

[image]

Use `ParametricPlot` to plot `x2` versus `x1`

```
ParametricPlot[{x1[y], x2[y]}, {y, 2.03, 6}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"x1", "x2"})]
```

[image]

`x2` is not expressible as a function of `x1` since the relationship is not single-valued over the range of interest. You could either restrict the range of interest to where the relationship is single-valued **or** break the range into regions using `Piecewise`, and then use `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: Thank you Bob Hanlon